# caret (^) in FS (gawk)

Tags: awk

### Update

This was a bug and a fix is available in [git repo](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gawk.git/commit/?id=847657fa4ec580658371d6fcaea547f7769fb569) now.

---

I can't understand how a circumflex in `FS` is interpreted.
For example, here is my `file`:

```
$ cat file
foo bar
baz quz
```

I wrote this awk script:

```
BEGIN{FS="^.";OFS="|"}{$1=$1}1
```

and was expecting this output:

```
|oo bar
|uz baz
```

but with gawk I got this:

```
$ gawk 'BEGIN{FS="^.";OFS="|"}{$1=$1}1' file
||o bar
||z quz
```

And it gets stranger with more dots:

```
$ gawk 'BEGIN{FS="^..";OFS="|"}{$1=$1}1' file
||bar
||quz
$ gawk 'BEGIN{FS="^...";OFS="|"}{$1=$1}1' file
||r
||z
$ gawk 'BEGIN{FS="^....";OFS="|"}{$1=$1}1' file
|bar
|quz
```

I couldn't find an explanation in neither [POSIX awk specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html) nor [gawk manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html). Can you guys please help me understand what's going on? What am I missing here?

Comment: hmm, `perl -F'^.' -lane 'print join "|", @F'` and `gawk 'BEGIN{FS="^[fb]";OFS="|"}{$1=$1}1'` behaves like you expected.. `gawk 'BEGIN{FS="^..";OFS="|"}{$1=$1}1'` again does two splits instead of one..

Comment: end of line anchor doesn't have an issue `gawk 'BEGIN{FS=".$";OFS="|"}{$1=$1}1'`

Comment: works if you manually print the fields instead of field rebuilding, `gawk 'BEGIN{FS="^.";OFS="|"}{print $1, $2}'` or use another field number, `gawk 'BEGIN{FS="^.";OFS="|"}{$2=$2}1'`

Comment: Old (not gnu) awk on Mac behaves as you expected.  (bsd awk version 20070501)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is clearly a bug and probably a memory leak. When you ask to print `NF` before, the behaviour is as expected:

```
$ gawk 'BEGIN{FS="^.";OFS="|"; $0="foo"; $1=$1; print}'
||oo
$ gawk 'BEGIN{FS="^.";OFS="|"; $0="foo"; $1=$1; print NF; print}'
2
|oo
```